# SQLite cursor randomly returning no results - what might be the cause?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to track down a bug I see coming back from remote crash uploads from my clients where it's as if there is no data in my SQLLiteDatabase when previously queries had been working fine and data was clearly present. For example, in this code here, assume that there is one Profiles table that holds one profile row:

```
Profile p = null;
SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
builder.setTables(ProfileDbKeys.PROFILES_TABLE_NAME);
builder.setProjectionMap(ProfileDbKeys.ColumnMap);
Cursor cursor = builder.query(db, ProfileDbKeys.ProfileFields, null, null, null, null, null, null);
if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
  p = Profile.fromCursor(cursor);
}

cursor.close();
```

Normally p is set to a value, but in some instances it remains null and causes a crash down the line. The crash itself is intentional, because if my client datastore isn't working I would rather crash the activity vs. potentially corrupt state further.

In my logs I know that there are no SQLLite exceptions being thrown; it's as if the database is empty.

Can anyone offer any insight into why the cursor.moveToNext() might return no data every so often?

Comment: Crashing apps are bad for users as they will think **they** have done something wrong while that is not the case, so show the user an appropriate error message telling them to close the app. And what happens if you recompile SQLite? Maybe the SQLite binary is corrupted.

Comment: Did you try calling moveToFirst() instead?

Comment: @Klaus yes the actual offending code in my app does use moveToFirst(), so I don't think it's that